# Assembly enter directive nesting level

Tags: assembly, masm, nested

I'm trying to understand what is the "nesting level" that enter directive can specify for procedure's stack frame mean. The intel instruction set reference manual says that:

> The nesting level determines the number of frame pointers that are copied into the “display area” of the new stack
>   frame from the preceding frame.

So the nesting level determines how many times EBP (frame pointer) will pushed into the "display area" - what exactly is this display area? the current stack frame?

I also read that the nesting level helping block structured languages, and intel also said so:

> The ENTER and companion LEAVE instructions are provided to support block structured languages.

Why is that supporting block structured languages? Are they storing each block local data seperately in the stack? (I am asking, I don't know).

So if someone can briefly explain me nesting level and what it's good for, i'll be very thankful.

[Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

Comment: It is my clear impression that the form where potentially several frame pointers are copied from parent to child scope (into what is called a _display area_ in the new stack frame) is not in common use. In fact, I have never seen it used. The compilers I've dealt with copy just the parent's stack frame pointer. Any enclosing scopes further out can be accessed by following the chain of frame pointers. This works better in recursive scenarios.

Comment: I know that the enter directive is not for use in recurive procedures, but i dont understand where it's do needed. I dont understand why the new "block" will need seperate stack frame if he isnt a new procedure call, and if it uses the same stack frame, why would he need more frame pointer instances? and why the frame pointer count limited to 31? (intel's manual)

Comment: The frame pointers copied to the display area in the current stack frame would be used to access local variables in enclosing scopes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Now can you please explain me why those scopes needs more frame pointers? As i understand what you explained the block has its own stack frame and by passing it the parent ebp he can access the parent's local data. Am I right? And why only 31 frame pointers can be passed?

Comment: As for the 31 number, I think that's just an arbitrary encoding limitation that Intel chose. And indeed, display pointers are never a requirement, but for languages where they can be applied, access to variables in scopes further out than the immediate parent can be coded more efficiently because you don't have to go through multiple frame pointer indirections to get to a particular variable.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!